# Alternative ways to display available rooms in drop-down menu?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

For some time now, I'm trying to generate a reservation form, where only available rooms are listed for the `arrival` and `departure` dates chosen in that same reservation form. Unfortunately, until now I didn't manage to do so.

I set out a question already on my previous attempt, without any success. => https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59083421/edit

I'm now trying to look for alternative ways to get there. For reference, please find my previous attempt below.

**Previous attempt: general idea**

Tried to send/receive an AJAX. Cannot reach the success stage, and the bug seem lie in the dataType the AJAX call is expecting/I'm sending (JS vs JSON). Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve this.

- When I use `format.js` in my controller, I do not reach the success stage in my ajax call
- when I use `render json: {:rooms => @rooms}` I do not reach my `hotels/rooms_availability.js.erb` file and subsequently am not able to insert my available rooms.

**Previous attempt: code**

reservations/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for [@hotel, @reservation] do |f|%>
  <div class="col col-sm-3">
    <%= f.input :arrival,
    as: :string,
    label:false,
    placeholder: "From",
    wrapper_html: { class: "inline_field_wrapper" },
    input_html:{ id: "start_date"} %>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-sm-3">
    <%= f.input :departure,
    as: :string,
    label:false,
    placeholder: "From",
    wrapper_html: { class: "inline_field_wrapper" },
    input_html:{ id: "end_date"} %>
  </div>

  <div class="col col-sm-4">
    <%= f.input :room_id, collection: @rooms %>
  </div>

  <%= f.button :submit, "Search", class: "create-reservation-btn"%>
<% end %>
```

script for reservations/new.html.erb

```
<script>
const checkIn = document.querySelector('#start_date');
const checkOut = document.querySelector('#end_date');
const checkInAndOut = [checkIn, checkOut];

checkInAndOut.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if ((checkIn.value.length > 0) && (checkOut.value.length > 0)){
    checkAvailability();
  }
  })
})

  function checkAvailability(){

    $.ajax({
      url: "<%= rooms_availability_hotel_path(@hotel) %>" ,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: "POST",
      data: `arrival=${start_date.value}&departure=${end_date.value}`,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('succes')
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(response) {
        console.log('failure')
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  };
</script>
```

hotels_controller

```
def rooms_availability
  hotel = Hotel.includes(:rooms).find(params[:id])
  arrival = Date.parse room_params[:arrival]
  departure = Date.parse room_params[:departure]
  time_span = arrival..departure
  @unavailable_rooms = Room.joins(:reservations).where(reservations: {hotel: hotel}).where("reservations.arrival <= ? AND ? >= reservations.departure", arrival, departure).distinct
  @hotel_cats = hotel.room_categories
  @hotel_rooms = Room.where(room_category: hotel_cats)
  @rooms = hotel_rooms - @unavailable_rooms
   render json: {:rooms => @rooms}  
#respond_to do |format|
    #format.js
  #end
end

def room_params
  params.permit(:arrival, :departure, :format, :id)
end
```

hotels/rooms_availability.js.erb

```
var selectList = document.getElementById('reservation_room_id')

function empty() {
  selectList.innerHTML = "";
}

empty();


    <% unless @rooms.empty? %>
      <% @rooms.each do |room|%>
        selectList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<option value="<%= room.id %>"><%= room.name %></option>');
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: what do u get as a response??

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the response to the question.

Comment: instead of respond to try adding `render json: {:rooms => @rooms} ` you will get the rooms as json object in js. iterate though the json object to create drop down options

Comment: also, check the format of the date you passing from js to ruby

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I tried what you proposed and this provides me with the 500 error message ```Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)```. The response text I get is:  ```"{"rooms":[{"id":8,"name":"3","room_category_id":4,"created_at":"2019-11-19T16:21:16.239Z","updated_at":"2019-11-19T16:21:16.239Z"},{"id":16,"name":"1","room_category_id":9,"created_at":"2019-11-26T11:40:16.951Z","updated_at":"2019-11-26T11:40:16.951Z"}]}"```. The date formats seem to parse successfully and are of the format Date.

Comment: whats your error in server log when you getting 500

Comment: I added it at the bottom of my question, as it's too long for a comment.

Comment: you are still getting invalid date error.....maybe the date is not in the ruby format

Comment: Added the logs of the dates as well.

Comment: Fixed, the invalid date issue (see also updated question)

Comment: you have multiple ways to populate the drop-down, `format.js` will access the room_availabilty.js.erb , `render json:` will give you rooms in json object and you have to iterate through and populate the dropdown from your js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203502/discussion-between-techquestion-and-abhishek-aravindan).